# Trying to create a form that autocompletes a URL

Tags: html

Noob Coder

Im trying to create a form that when i fill it and click submit, it will autocomplete the URL and will load the correct page.

```html
  <html>
  <body>

<form>
<input type="text" id="search">
</form>

<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="myFunction()">


<script>
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("search").innerHTML ;
  var "searchInput" = ("search").val();
   var url = "https://=" + "searchInput" + ".igniter.store/uc_admin";


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Gino, Thanks for this, As im very new here, im still learning how to post things. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```html
<html>
        <body>

            <form>
             <input type="text" id="search">
            </form>

            <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="myFunction()">


            <script>
            function myFunction() {
                 var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
                 var url = "https://" + search + ".igniter.store/uc_admin";
                 window.location = url
            };
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```